# Angular StaticInjectorError Error

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm writing a library which need to wrap [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/).

Everything (the library and the consumer application) compiles fine, but on runtime in the browser I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[InjectionToken DocumentToken]: 
  StaticInjectorError[InjectionToken DocumentToken]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken DocumentToken!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:993)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10878)
    at _createClass (core.js:10919)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:10889)
```

***Abbreviated code:***

**Library module:**  Defines the `NgModule` for my library, imports the `OAuthModule` and the `HttpClientModule` which it requires.  Defines my `SomeService` service.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ HttpClientModule, OAuthModule.forRoot() ],
    providers: [ SomeService ]
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

**Library service:** Minimum example, does nothing but instantiate the OAuthService.

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    constructor(private oauth: OAuthService) {}
}
```

**Consumer app module:**  Just imports my library as `SomeModule`.

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [ SomeModule ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Consumer component:** Tries to call the `SomeService` service in my library, *which spawns the error.*

```
@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(
        private someService: SomeService
    ) {}
}
```

- The library and application both compile without error
- When I go to the app in the browser, I get the error mentioned above
- If I remove `HttpClientModule` from the library imports, it says I'm missing `HttpClient` instead of the error above
- Library is built with [angular-library-seed](https://github.com/trekhleb/angular-library-seed)
- Application is built with `@angular/cli`

I've tried many things, such as...

- Having the application also import `OAuthModule`
- Removing the `.forRoot()` on `OAuthModule.forRoot()` in the library means the library can't get to the services inside `OAuthModule`
- Changing the library to also use `.forRoot()`, with just about every combination of services in the `providers` array (between itself, OAuthService, and HttpClientService).
- Changing the webpack config to not list @angular/* as externals
- Changing the webpack config to list the OAuth library as an external
- Using rollup instead of webpack, with configs from two separate seed projects
- More things that boiled down to just grasping at straws

Googling around, it seems this error can happen when they are missing something obvious in the providers array on their NgModule; that doesn't seem to apply to me.  I don't use "*DocumentToken*" anywhere.

I've also seen a common fix is to import `HttpClientModule`, which I've already done to no avail.

I found exactly one instance of someone else getting this error with "DocumentToken".  They fixed their library in [this commit](https://github.com/material-extended/mde/commit/e557e72a64766ad3e9970d1958fec8ddce0d3fa9), which seemed to just add more externals to their rollup config.  While my library uses webpack, it uses [webpack-angular-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-angular-externals) to make sure all @angular/* packages are listed as external.

Any help or ideas would be extremely, extremely appreciated.

(Angular 5, TypeScript 2.6.2)

Comment: You should either declare `AppComponent` in the `SomeModule` declarations or provide `SomeService` in the `AppModule`. At least try this, i might be mistaken:)

Comment: Unfortunately, `AppComponent` and `SomeModule` exist in different projects.  The `AppComponent` is part of the app, and `SomeModule` is the library NgModule.

Comment: Do you use aot build? It could be that OAuthModule does not support it.

Comment: I am not really great at understanding angular under hood, but perhaps its that `AppComponent` tries to use `SomeService` but as it is external one it could not yet be loaded, or something like that. If it is possible, try adding `SomeService` to `AppModule` providers and see if that resolves the error

Comment: The only information about DocumentToken is in CommonModule source code. So it must be you need to import in your modules. [Document DI Source In Common Module][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/54e02449549448ebab6f255f2da0b4396665c6f0/packages/common/src/dom_tokens.ts

Comment: @Mike, did you solve this issue? I run into it as well

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I opened a GitHub issue with a set of repos to easily reproduce the problem:  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21426

Comment: I had the same issue (still kind of do) but I was able to get the browser to serve the page without showing the error but it still shows in the server logs. In my case I split the auth module into a server and browser module and I missed old code that was lazy loading the browser module on the root path. I haven't discovered a fix for the server log error but at least the page loads and auth works. I threw up a demo for my current state. https://github.com/thebaron24/angular-oauth2-oidc-ssr